# Alter table on id only

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to set the Auto Increment of my tables st_id to = 201406001

**query:**

```
ALTER TABLE
support_ticket AUTO_INCREMENT=201406001
```

When doing this it worked and now my "st_id" (AI, Primary key) is set to 201406001 just as I wanted.

When I ran that query it said it affected 4 rows which is right, because there were 4 rows in the table when I ran that query.

But now when I try and update the status of a specific column in one of those 4 rows, it will not update.

Is my ALTER TABLE query wrong?

I tried running the following query to only target the st_id like this, but gave me an error.

```
ALTER TABLE
support_ticket.st_id AUTO_INCREMENT=201406001
FROM
support_ticket
```

**ERROR**

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL  server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
support_ticket' at line 3
```

So my question is, should I stick with my original query, as it did work, or should I try to get the 2nd query working?

Also, could running that 1st query be that be the reason I cannot update my column now?

This is my first time using ALTER TABLE so any help would be of use.

**Here is my update code:**
Form

```
<form method="POST" action="close.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="st_id" value="<?php echo escape ($t->st_id); ?>">
<h3>Close this ticket...</h3>
<select name="status">
<option value="<?php echo escape($t->status); ?>">Current Status: OPEN</option>
<option value="0">CLOSE</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="CLOSE"><input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="window.location = '/admin/maintenance/'">
</form>
```

**Action script:**

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/core/init.php");

$st_id = $_POST['st_id'];

$status = $_POST['status'];

$updatestatus = DB::getInstance()->UPDATE('support_ticket', $st_id, array(
    'status' => $status,
));


echo "The ticket was successfully closed.<br />
```

**Solution to my UPDATE problem:**
Finally got it to update by this:

```
$st_id = $_POST['st_id'];

$status = $_POST['status'];

$updatestatus = DB::getInstance()->query("UPDATE `support_ticket` SET `status` = $status WHERE `st_id` = $st_id");
```

Comment: My st_id is the only auto_increment in the table

Comment: @user0000000 could running the query be effecting my updating columns ability? I'm 99% sure that my update code is correct.

Comment: question 2) you want to set a st_id = 201406001
?

Comment: @user0000000 see at top of page for UPDATE

Comment: The one that's giving you an error, shouldn't that be along the lines of `ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN column_name...`?

Comment: `alter` does not have a `from` argument... you're not moving data around o rselecting data from elsewhere. you're just changing the table's metadata and/or structure. There's no "from" involved with that.

Comment: Okay so I must have an error in my UPDATE code is guess. If you spot it like me know, but I'm using the same code elsewhere and it works perfect. Also I get no error when updating. It just doesn't update the column row

Comment: By the way, the syntax is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and not `enctype="form-data"`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for that spot, but still not updating.

Comment: You're welcome. You will need to update your question with the SQL's UPDATE codes. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and if using PDO, also add `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened, if you're not already doing so, while replacing `$pdo` with your PDO connection variable.

Comment: @ Fred -ii- Not sure what you mean by, "You will need to update your question with the SQL's UPDATE codes."

Also, I have error reporting turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to trial to auto-increment according to year or month. You can use [MySQL Custom AUTO_INCREMENT values](http://en.latindevelopers.com/ivancp/2012/custom-auto-increment-values/)  as follows: 
(read the article first)

I changed the function `getNextCustomSeq` the line:

```
SET @ret = (SELECT concat(sSeqGroup,'-',lpad(nLast_val,6,'0')));
```

to

```
SET @ret = (SELECT concat(sSeqGroup,lpad(nLast_val,3,'0')));
```

Then I create table and triggeras follows:

```
CREATE TABLE ticket(
  id int not null primary key auto_increment,
  autonum int not null  
);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER ticket_autonums_bi BEFORE INSERT ON ticket
FOR each ROW
BEGIN
   SET NEW.autonum = getNextCustomSeq(date_format(now(),'%Y%m'),date_format(now(),'%Y%m'));
END$$
delimiter ;
```

Note: The function `date_format(now(),'%Y%m')` will return current year and mont like "201406"

Now insert some values:

```
insert into ticket(id) 
values (null),(null),(null),(null),(null),
(null),(null),(null),(null),(null);
```

Select the inserted data:

```
mysql> select * from ticket;
+----+-----------+
| id | autonum   |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | 201406001 |
|  2 | 201406002 |
|  3 | 201406003 |
|  4 | 201406004 |
|  5 | 201406005 |
|  6 | 201406006 |
|  7 | 201406007 |
|  8 | 201406008 |
|  9 | 201406009 |
| 10 | 201406010 |
+----+-----------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: as of right now at the first of every month we will have to run that ALTER TABLE query to give the st_id a new st_id for that month. I.E. next month we will run it again and it will be 201407001 = 2014 Year 07 Month 001 Ticket #. Reading through this are you saying we can generate the st_id each month automatically to update the year/date/001? If so that would be a very helpful solution, so we don't have to manually do it each month.

FYI this is for a support ticket system. Thats why we need the st_id set like that. We are using it for a ticket #

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE ... AUTO_INCREMENT=201406001` only means that the *next* AI value generated will be that value. It doesn't change the id value in any of the current rows of data in the table.

The "affected rows" message meant that it performed a table copy as part of the ALTER TABLE. Some older versions of MySQL would naively copy all the rows in the table, even though you wouldn't think it had to to perform the metadata change.

So if you try to `UPDATE ... WHERE id=201406001` it will not apply to your existing rows.

Comment: So are you saying because I ran that query I cannot update the existing rows?

Comment: I'm saying the id's of existing rows did not change as a result of the ALTER TABLE, so you would have to use the "old" values in a WHERE clause, not any value 201406001 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

With `ALTER` you update your tabledescription (ie columnnames, values for autoincrement).

If you want to update the values of a table you have to use `UPDATE`. ie:

```
UPDATE support_ticket SET status = 'closed' WHERE id = 1234;
```

If you're new to SQL have a look at w3schools.com. they have some tutorials (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

Comment: Got it updated by doing the following: See top for my update solution. @chresse